# Надеть или обуть

Tags: глаголы

Как правильно сказать ребенку: "Давай наденем сандалии" или "Давай обуем сандалии"?

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос. 
*Обуть сандалии* - неправильно. **Обуть** можно ребенка, а сандалии только **набуть**.
Тут тот же случай, что и с одеть-надеть. Одежду надевают, Надежду одевают.

Но с другой стороны, **надевать обувь** тоже до недавнего времени считалось неправильным. Так что маму вашу тоже в чем-то можно понять. Однако в последнее время глагол "набуть" практически вышел из употребления. Сейчас возражать против **одеть сандалии** может только самый ярый пурист-консерватор.

//------------------------

Попался вопрос два года спустя...

Знаете, я несколько изменил мнение. Т.е. касательно "набуть сандалии" все в силе.
А вот "одеть сандалии" стало резать слух. Возможно, я сам стал пуристом.
Так что остается только **надеть сандалии**. против чего не возражал, естественно, никто.

Comment: То есть до внесения последнего уточнения вы были согласны с оборотом одеть сандалии?