# Есть ли в русском языке глагол "набуть"?

Tags: лексика

Есть ли в русском языке глагол "набуть" в смысле "надеть" обувь? Ни в словарях, ни в интернете мне найти не удалось этот глагол. А вот здесь [Надеть или обуть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C) один человек утверждает, что есть. Может, я неправ, но мне кажется, что рекомендация неверна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В русских говорах это слово встречается.

См. [**Словарь русских говоров Сибири**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=EoppAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ26GSvp7jAhVc4KYKHUDWCM4Q6AEILzAB). Под ред. А.И. Федорова / Изд. "Наука". Новосибирск, 2001]:

> НАГНАТЬ БОЛЯЧКИ. Натереть мозоли. — *Нагнала себе болячки сёдни.
>   **Набуть** ничо нельзя.* Новосиб., Татар.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол "набуть" сейчас в русском языке не фиксируется. Насколько понимаю, речь идет о исторической и/или диалектной форме.

Дело не только в аналогии с одеть-надеть, хотя она есть, прямая и очевидная - корень "у", "о/на" - приставка (совершенно не понимаю, чем она так досадила "предыдущему оратору").

Это слово постоянно всплывает в разговорной речи, речи детей. Можно предположить, что оно когда-то существовало. Можно также погуглить, если даже исключить ссылки на этот ресурс, найдется масса свидетельств в постоянном желании это слово реконструировать.

Короче вопрос упирается в трактовку того, что такое "существует ли слово?". Если ограничиваться только современной нормой, то нет. Но вообще-то в каком-то смысле оно существует.

Comment: Понятно. Значит, рекомендация неверна.Спасибо.

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 - ***Как рекомендация использовать "набуть" в нормированной речи, разумеется, не верна***. Но в плане рассуждений о том, почему нельзя использовать "обуть сапоги" вполне интересна.

Comment: >> *Но в плане рассуждений...*. Для любителей-рассуждалкиных – это да. Ничего, что "обуть сапоги" – вполне нормальное, грамотное сочетание. Главное – порассуждать.

Comment: *Ничего, что "обуть сапоги" – вполне нормальное* - ничего грамотного, вы хотите сказать?  .

Comment: Кстати, вы так и не спросили у зала. Ничего, что "о/об" и "об/обо" - это разные приставки? "обить" и "оббить? "означать" и "обозначать"?

Comment: >> *ничего грамотного, вы хотите сказать?* Понятно, г-н @Morkovkin, что вы сами себе грамматика, но в словари все же надо заглядывать. Иногда, чтоб уж совсем не отрываться от народа )

Comment: @Niemand Без комментариев.